# How to improve CSS performance of iOS hamburger menu?

Tags: ios, css, animation, mobile

I have a responsive mobile site and I'm creating a CSS hamburger menu (a panel menu that slides out).

The way I have implemented it is quite simple (I opted not to use any existing framework). It works by using the `transition` property at `left .3s ease-in-out`, and manipulating the `left` property.

The performance is quite poor in all browers. It's definitely "acceptable" but its not perfectly smooth.

Unfortunately, so far *all* the scripts I'm finding have the same sluggish performance. [This one](http://www.ymc.ch/sandbox/hamburger/mobile-menu-demo.html) for instance looks great, but is sluggish.

Now, there is one exception... [THIS menu](http://www.andrewgreig.com/demo/bamboo/#) somehow works so amazingly and perfectly smooth. It's flawless... but I can't figure out how he did it. If you dont see the menu, resize the browser small until it appears.

His JS and CSS really break my site severely, which is why I can't really use it. It's not even worth modifying his code. But I'd love to know which part of his CSS really makes it so smooth.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add the following to your nav

```
transform: translateZ(0);
```

This will kick in the hardware acceleration and make the transition alot smoother

You could also help it along by adding

```
transition: all 0.6s ease;
perspective: 1000;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Comment: Thanks! can you explain how `perspective` and `-webkit-backface-visibility` help?

Comment: they both help prevent the flicker of the sliding element when using translateX/Y/Z

Answer (score 0):

The first one that you linked has an `animation-timing-function` of `ease-out` I think, while the second one that you say is very smooth is definitely a linear one.

This is just a small suggestion, but try changing your code from

```
left .3s ease-in-out
```

to

```
left .3s linear
```

maybe it will help.

EDIT: Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c9Ltz/) I made for you, maybe it can help you determine which option renders the best.

I got mixed results in Chrome. Using the `transform: translateX()` function, the animation is smoother. In Firefox they all look the same.